# Applying simple regex pattern to SQL query

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I want to retrieve all rows that have that have a certain column with only 2 words. I tried this, but it failed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sentence FROM vocab WHERE p='adj' AND sentence REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$'
```

This doesn't seem to work. Words can have ! or ? in it, so I don't think `[a-zA-Z]` is appropriate either way.

EDIT: I should rephrase it a bit, it should match any "group" of characters. Meaning

> xczc zczxc~
>
> 1233 iojsd
>
> ´+a  s~º

Could I use something like (.*) ?

Comment: Besides "!" or "?" can words have any other symbols or numbers within them?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]+[[:space:]][a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: `^[\s]*[\w!?]+\s[\w!?]+[\s]*$`  you could add more non-word chars as needed. Also account for whitespace before first and after second word

Comment: @NachtBlaad yes, I probably need to rephrase it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL doesn't support `\s`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) so you can use `[[:space:]]` instead, you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sentence 
FROM vocab 
WHERE p='adj' 
AND sentence RLIKE '^[[:punct:][:alnum:]]+[[:space:]][[:punct:][:alnum:]]+$'
```

It'll look for rows where sentence is 2 words which may contain letters, `?` or `!`

**[Sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df923a/2)**

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well, it should actually include several characters (not just ! or ?). Please see my update. Could I use (.*) ?

Comment: @Cornwell The problem wiht using `.*` is that it includes spaces as well, see my updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty but this should work

```
'^[a-zA-Z?!]+[[:space:]][a-zA-Z?!]+$'
```